# Django signal received not being called

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I've used Django signals in the past. I'm working on a 1.10 app now, and for some reason I cannot get my receiver to be called.

app1/signals.py

```
from django.dispatch import Signal
list_member_updated = Signal(providing_args=['list_member_id',])
```

app1/models.py

```
print('Dispatching signal...')
list_member_updated.send(self.__class__, list_member_id=list_member.id)
```

app1/apps.py

```
class DjangoApp1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'app1'

    def ready(self):
        import app1.signals
```

app2/util.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from app1.signals import list_member_updated

@receiver(list_member_updated)
def handle_member_updated(sender, **kwargs):
    print('Received signal')
```

So I get the "Signal dispatched..." in the console, but not the "Received signal". I have a feeling I'm missing something simple, but I just cannot see it.

Answer (score 2):

In **app1/__init__.py** add the mentioned line. it worked for me

```
default_app_config = 'app1.apps.DjangoApp1Config'
```

Note: The app1/__init__.py bits are not required if you are already referring to your AppConfig in the **INSTALLED_APPS** settings.

You can refer to [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) for more details.